# connecting Ruby to Mysql without rails

Tags: ruby

How can i connect Ruby to Mysql without rails?
I want to use Ruby standalone to write pure ruby code to make web application.
with no abstraction

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look here

```
require "mysql"    # if needed

@db_host  = "localhost"
@db_user  = "root"
@db_pass  = "root"
@db_name = "your_db_name"

client = Mysql::Client.new(:host => @db_host, :username => @db_user, :password => @db_pass, :database => @db_name)
@cdr_result = client.query("SELECT * from your_db_table_name')
```

Comment: Thanks, in this case i can connect to Mysql and use it and upload my .rb files on a web server and my app should work with no need for using Rails right?

Comment: Can't edit the answer but your last quote should be double-quote :)

Answer (score 12):

What about using ActiveRecord ORM?

```
require 'mysql2'
require "active_record"

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => 'mysql',
  :database => 'database',
  :username => 'user',
  :password => 'password',
  :host     => 'localhost')


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Comment: Megas, thanks for your answer, Rails frustriated me, I wanted to use ruby just like the way i use PHP without any framework, only web server mysql and the ruby interpreter installed. is there is a way to develop website using this method like php? it needs templates, and i don't know how to create one, i embeded ruby code inside html changed the file to .rb or .erb nothing worked. i don't want to use rails or any framework i want to learn how to build from scratch using my own way. thank you for your answer again :)

Answer (score 11):

install `gem mysql` (check that you have libmysqlclient-dev installed).

```
mysql = Mysql.new(host, user, password, database)
mysql.query("SELECT ...")
mysql.close
```

[See the documentation for more information](http://www.tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/)

Answer (score 5):

For mysql2:

```
1) yum install mysql-devel
2) gem install mysql2
```

Connect:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "mysql2"

connect = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "hostname", :username => "username", :password => "password", :database => "name_db")
result = connect.query("SELECT * FROM table_name")
result.each {  |x| puts x }
```

Comment: what does |x| puts x mean